# Found routing for relay modern is not working

Tags: reactjs, relay

I am trying to implement relay-found for my application. But the routing is not working properly. The route http://localhost:3000/ displays a blank page while http://localhost:3000/logo and http://localhost:3000/text render the same Text component. I cannot able to find out the exact problem. Please help.

```
I have two components.

import React from 'react';

export function Logo() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p> Logo component </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export function Text() {
    return (
        <div>
          Text Component    
        </div>
    )

}
```

And my routing is as given below:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

import { BrowserProtocol, queryMiddleware } from "farce";
import { createFarceRouter, createRender, makeRouteConfig, Route } from "found";
import { Resolver } from "found-relay";
import environment from "./Environment";
import { graphql } from "react-relay";
import { Logo, Text } from "./Logo";
import App from "./App";

/* ... */
const profileQuery = graphql`
    query src_Profile_Query($userId: ID!) {
        userProfile(id: $userId) {
            id
            email
        }
    }
`;

const Router = createFarceRouter({
    historyProtocol: new BrowserProtocol(),
    historyMiddlewares: [queryMiddleware],
    routeConfig: makeRouteConfig(
        <Route
            path="/"
            Component={Text}
            query={profileQuery}
            prepareVariables={params => ({
                ...params,
                userId: "VXNlclByb2ZpbGVOb2RlOjc1"
            })}
        >
            <Route path="text" Component={Text} />
            <Route path="logo" Component={Logo} />
        </Route>
    ),

    render: createRender({})
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router resolver={new Resolver(environment)} />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And the Environment:

```
import { Environment, Network, RecordSource, Store } from "relay-runtime";

function fetchQuery(operation, variables) {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8000/graphql/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: operation.text,
            variables
        })
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    });
}

const environment = new Environment({
    network: Network.create(fetchQuery),
    store: new Store(new RecordSource())
});

export default environment;
```

Answer (score 0):

I promised myself I'd circle back and help you out once I found a solution, as I was experiencing the same problem and I believe we're working from the same [reference example](https://github.com/taion/relay-todomvc/tree/found-modern).

I exhausted the following:

- Matching the exact package includes from the reference project.
- Literally pulling the reference project itself and trying to modify it.
- Trying every possible permutation of React component styles.
- Trying every possible permutation of routing configuration.

I finally dug into the Found router source and decided to give the following a try (with great success):

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'found'

...

const Router = createBrowserRouter({
    historyMiddleware: [queryMiddleware],
    routeConfig: routes
})
```

I don't know if there's currently an unaddressed bug in the `farce` router that is used by the reference application or if perhaps it has some quietly unfulfilled dependency on redux (as it uses redux internally), but this router version worked fine for me!